# How to read object in JS send from JSP by AJAX

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I don't know, how to read dates from response's object.
I send from servlet to javascript two strings(isValid, liczbaObiektow) and and far more objects of type Miasto. I try to display "Krakow" by this code alert(data+'.'+tnp) but that not working.

My files with source codes:

index.jsp :

```
<body>

    <label>Wojewodztwo</label>
    <select id="woj" name="wojewodztwa" size="1">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Wybierz Wojewodztwo</option>
          <option value="2">Małopolskie</option>
          <option value="4">Mazowieckie</option>
      </select>
      <BR/>
      <BR/>
      <BR/>
      <label>Miasta</label>
      <select id="miasto" name="miasta" size="1">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Wybierz miasto</option>
      </select>
      <BR/>
      <BR/>
      <BR/>
      <label>Zabytki</label>
      <select name="zabytki" size="1">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Wybierz artefakt</option>
      </select>
</body>
```

ajax.js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$('#miasto').append('<option value="test2">test2</option>');      
    //$('select[name="miasta"]').append('<option value="test2">Monarchia</option>');    

    var tnp;
    $('#woj').change(function () {
        //alert('Tui2');
        //var b = $(this).val();
        //alert(b);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'update',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#woj').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.isValid){
                    alert(data.liczbaObiektow);
                    for(var i=0; i < data.liczbaObiektow; ++i) {
                        tnp = 'a'+i;
                        alert(data+'.'+tnp);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    alert('Please enter a vaild username');
                }
            }
        }); 

    });
});
```

update.java :

```
class Miasto {
    int idMiasta;
    String opisMiasta;
    Miasto(int idMiasta, String opisMiasta) {
        this.idMiasta = idMiasta;
        this.opisMiasta = opisMiasta;
    }
}

@WebServlet("/update")
public class UpdateUsername extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean isValid;


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
        //sc.setAttribute("username", "sex");
        isValid = false;
        String wojewodztwo = request.getParameter("wojewodztwa");
        Map <String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        if ( wojewodztwo != null && wojewodztwo.trim().length() != 0 ) {

            if(wojewodztwo.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                map.put("liczbaObiektow", "2");
                map.put("a1", new Miasto(22, "Krakow"));
                map.put("a2", new Miasto(33, "Nowa-Huta"));
            }
            else {
                map.put("liczbaObiektow", "3");
                map.put("a1", new Miasto(22, "Warszawa"));
                map.put("a2", new Miasto(33, "Starowka"));
                map.put("a3", new Miasto(33, "Twoja stara"));
            }

            isValid = true;
            //map.put("username", wojewodztwo);
            map.put("isValid", isValid);
            write(response, map);
        } else {
            map.put("isValid", isValid);
            write(response, map);
        }
    }

    private void write(HttpServletResponse response, Map<String, Object> map) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(map));
    }

}
```

Thank You very much for helping.

Comment: Try with `console.log(data);` in the success call ;)

Comment: You say that your response type is JSON (`dataType: 'json'`) so this line `data.isValid()` will not work - check that your response is valid JSON first? (as @RobertRozas said, using `console.log(data)` )

Comment: if(data.isValid) is working correct, but i don't know to read "Krakow" is JS as value

Comment: ok I know now. For example a2 is a Object but if I call data.a1.opisMiasta I will get the Cracow. Thx for Robert and blurfus for showing me, the method console.log. It is very useful.